# Swift: Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CGColor"

Tags: ios, core-animation, swift, cgcolor

I'm trying to animate the background color of a view. In the `animationDidStop` delegate method I try to set the final background color using the `toValue` property of the `CABasicAnimation` object. The code seems right in the editor but when I compile the project the linker doesn't find the `CGColor` class. The code works if I omit the `UIColor(CGColor: animation.toValue as CGColor!`) expression (for example using a const `UIColor`)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func colorSelected(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
        animation.toValue = sender.backgroundColor.CGColor
        animation.delegate = self
        self.view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "fadeAnimation")
    }

    @objc override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
        let animation = anim as CABasicAnimation
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(CGColor: animation.toValue as CGColor!)
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:** with Xcode 6 beta 3 the code compiles but an exception is raised in method `swift_dynamicCastUnknownClassUnconditional` where the `toValue` property is casted to `CGColor`.

This weird behavior seems to be related to some Xcode issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to a compiler bug, as clarified by Apple in [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1001260#1001260) forum thread. A radar was requested and filed: 17603642.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the class is `CGColorRef` and not CGColor. CGColor is the property on UIColor to get CGColorRef like  `[UIColor redColor].CGColor`

Comment: rewritten as        
`let color : CGColorRef = animation.toValue as CGColorRef`
`self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(CGColor: color)`
I got the same linker error

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(CGColorRef: color)`??